# Itunes app - mapping countries and languages

Tags: itunes, app-store-connect

Itunes allows developers to customize the title, descriptions and screen shots in about a dozen languages. Now, how does apple choses which languages to show for which country?

Some of them are straight forward - like using English for US or Australia. But how about options for both French and English in France? Or Spanish or English in Spain?
Which is the default language used?

I couldn't find out as to where it is specified, if it is so.

Comment: I believe this actually feeds off a user's own preferences; if you open iTunes, go to the iTunes Store and scroll to the end of the page, you'll see a country flag in the bottom-right corner. Click this and the user can set the language they want to view iTunes in. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, as an user I can chose the preference. What I would like to know is the default language that is chosen for an user coming from Country X.